# Yosemite grey background on login screen

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, login

I recently installed yosemite (fresh install) on my mbp retina and i notice that the login screen has a grey background with only my account pic. I can login normally and without any problems but it is strange that i don't see the blurry background.
This happens only when i login from normal startup and not after waking from sleep mode.
Is there a way to force embed the blurry background on the login screen?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The grey screen during boot is new to Yosemite and no, there is no way to disable it.

Comment: Strange because i ve seen yosemite login screen with blur background on another macbook pro direct from boot.

Comment: Are you sure it was from boot? The blur is there after the boot up sequence, but the boot starts with a  grey screen and a progress bar. The login screen will then stay grey (FileVault enabled) or switch to a blurred screen (FileVault disabled) but it always starts with the grey screen now, at leas wont eh machines here.

Comment: Good comment about FileVault